# Multi-View TableView with RootController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create a multi-view app with navigation template. I want table on the bottom part of initial view, with other views (image view, labels, etc) on the top.

Originally I modified RootViewController.xib to resize tableview, and added image view, but nothing displayed except full-size table.

So I  modified RootViewController.xib to add UIView, then added a UITableView and UIImageView to that view. I added IBOutlet for the tableView. In my RootViewController.xib, File'S Owner (RootViewController) has outlet connection to the view and the table view. When I right-click the UITableView, I see the referencing outlet to File's Owner. When I right-click the UIView, I see the referencing outlet to File's Owner. (I don't have an outlet to UIImageView, since I don't modify in code; do I need one?).

However, when I launch the app, it crashes with message:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>       reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "RootViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *QuizIdentifier = @"QuizIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:QuizIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:QuizIdentifier]
                autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    UIImage *_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];
    cell.imageView.image = _image;

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_categories objectAtIndex:row];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because when you create a navigation-based iOS app, Xcode makes the RootViewController a subclass of `UITableViewController`. Once you combine that `UITableView` with a normal `UIView`, your subclass no longer complies with the `UITableViewController` class. So, in your RootViewController.m and .h files change `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`. You may also need to change a few other things in your `init` method, but let's just start with this.

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"\n\nI'm in Root / cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    static NSString *QuizIdentifier = @"QuizIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = 
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:QuizIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:QuizIdentifier]
                autorelease];
        UIImage *_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];
        cell.imageView.image = _image;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_categories objectAtIndex:row];

    NSLog(@"  We are at row %i with label %@ ", row, cell.textLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: OK, I changed UITableViewController to UIViewController in RootViewController.h; now image view displays, as does blank table. Seems like a regular View-Based app rather than Navigation-Based app. Is there still a reason to use Navigation template in this case?

Comment: OK, works so far; however, I'm having a problem displaying cell properties. I load cell.textLabel.text from an [array objectAtIndex:row] message and it displays correctly; however when I try to set the accessory type or an image it doesn't display: cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png];           so I can't can't these properties to display. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the whole `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method?

Comment: What do you mean? Select the code in Xcode, copy it, then click edit under your question and paste it in. and make sure you use code formatting when pasting.

Comment: I cut and paste into this 'add comment' box, but all it says is nnn characters left, pressing add comment button doesn't do anything...

Comment: Put it in your original question. It would be nearly impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: actually it says -188 characters left--is there a limit of charaters? Do I need to do 'Add Comments' multiple times?

Comment: Are you even reading my responses? "Put it in your original question. It would be nearly impossible to read in a comment."

Comment: I did read your response, and responded earlier before your newest response. The cellForRowAtIndexPath has been added to original question. Thanx

Comment: Try removing the ".png" from the `imageNamed:` call. I'm not sure about the accessory view problem.

Comment: OK, I removed ".png", but didn't change anything

Comment: Tried it, still not displaying image or disclosure arrow

Comment: No, nothing except my NSLog displays

Comment: That's weird, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. I don't know what else to try, sorry.